# How to reset string value from java in Android?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android, so I hope everyone can help me to change String in strings.xml from programming.

Here is the original string:

```
<string name="cv_name">Hong Sengheng</string>
```

And I want to reset it's value to Sengheng.

```
<string name="cv_name">Sengheng</string>
```

So, hopefully everyone give me idea.

Comment: can you explain why you want to reset the string value?

Answer (score 0):

One thing what you have to understand here is that, when you provide a data as a Resource, it can't be modified during run time. For example, the drawables what you have in your drawable folder can't be modified at run time. To be precise, the "res" folder can't be modified programatically.

This applies to Strings.xml also, i.e "Values" folder. If at all you want a String which has to be modified at runtime, create a separate class and have your strings placed in this Class and access during run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the value of String.xml at runtime but you can change the text of that particular Ui where you pass that String...

Answer (score 0):

You cann't change the value of string.xml at the runtime for this u can make a seprate class and change string value at the run time and use it

Answer (score 0):

while the value of a resource should not be changed programmatically you can certainly assign a string resource to a variable String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring_res); and then change that variable's value mystring="new value";